# (Scheme) Is it possible to return one of two values depending on input, using only define or math statements?

Tags: scheme

The user inputs a number. When the number is above a specified amount, something happens. Something else happens if the number is below the specified amount, instead. Is it possible to achieve this without using any booleans/conditionals/ifs? As in purely through mathematical operations or function definitions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with [sgn](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=sgn#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fmath..rkt%29._sgn%29%29) and a [hash table](http://docs.racket-lang.org/guide/hash-tables.html?q=hash), for example (in Racket):

```
(define trigger-value 42) ; this is the reference value

(define action   ; defines the actions that should happen
  (hash 
   -1 (lambda () (displayln "below"))
    0 (lambda () (displayln "BINGO"))
   +1 (lambda () (displayln "above"))))

(define (test n) ; calls the right action procedure depending on n
  ((hash-ref action (sgn (- n trigger-value)))))
```

The expression `(- n trigger-value)` is negative when n < trigger-value, positive when n > trigger- value, and 0 if they are the same. Applying `sgn` to that value yields in -1, 0 or 1, respectively. That value is then used to look in the hash table which procedure should be called.

Here, the procedures just display a line, but they could also return a value, for example, which could then be used for further calculations.

testing

```
> (test 11)
below
> (test 90)
above
> (test 42)
BINGO
```

**EDIT** 
This is the solution mentioned by @Chris in the comments:

```
(define action  
  (list
   (lambda () (displayln "below"))
   (lambda () (displayln "BINGO"))
   (lambda () (displayln "above"))))

(define (test n) ; calls the right action procedure depending on n
  ((list-ref action (add1 (sgn (- n trigger-value))))))
```

and this is based on alists:

```
(define action  
  (list
   (list -1 (lambda () (displayln "below")))
   (list  0 (lambda () (displayln "BINGO")))
   (list +1 (lambda () (displayln "above")))))

(define (test n) ; calls the right action procedure depending on n
  ((second (assv (sgn (- n trigger-value)) action))))
```

Comment: You don't even need a hash table. Just add 1 and use `list-ref`.

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young True, that would work, as would alists. I chose hash tables because they are the most reusable approach, since they can be used with any kind of key, not only numerics. And for larger action tables, hash lookup is more efficient than alists.